# Efecto de texto en JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-css

Quiero hacer un efecto para cuando el ratón pase por encima del texto pero no sé como hacerlo. Sería ago [así](https://gyazo.com/b16aa7c5faeb4eff253ca5f728be3295), qué al pasar el ratón por encima, el color pasara a ser el del fondo y que las letras tuvieran borde. La parte de canviar de color el texto se puede hacer perfectamente con CSS pero lo de añadir ese borde no sé como hacerlo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el `setBorder` pero te hará borde a todo el nodo, incluyendo el *padding*, pero si lo que quieres es un efecto de sombra a el texto, puedes utilizar el *DropShadow*:

```
DropShadow dropShadow = new DropShadow(15);
Label label = new Label("Ejemplo de Label");
label.setEffect(dropShadow);
```

Answer (score 0):

**seudoclase hover**

[image: hover text javafx]

se puede hacer ese efecto en css con la seudoclase hover que aplica su regla cuando el puntero está sobre el nodo . se prepara el borde para que sea negro `text.setStroke(Color.BLACK);` . Después se da una clase a `text`  para poder ser accesible en css `text.getStyleClass().add("customtext");`

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        Text text = new Text( "EnglishAppJavaFX");
        text.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        text.setFont(new Font(70));
        text.getStyleClass().add("customtext");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(text), 640, 480);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("text.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

text.css

```
.customtext:hover{
    -fx-fill:transparent;   
}
```